# Why std::filesystem::path("//.") is not the same as std::filesystem::path("//") / std::filesystem::path(".")?

Tags: c++, path, filesystems, std

```
#include <filesystem>

using namespace std::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    assert(path("//.").string() == path("//") / path(".").string());
    assert(path("//.").root_directory() == (path("//") / path(".")).root_directory());

    assert(path("//.").root_directory().string() == (path("//") / path(".")).root_directory().string());

    return 0;
}
```

The code will fail on third assert(...).

```
path("//.").root_directory().string() gives "/".
(path("//") / path(".")).root_directory().string() gives "//".
```

Is that correct behavior?

I tried this example on ArchLinux, GCC 10.2.0.

Comment: What happens if you convert them to an absolute canonical path?  q.v. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/canonical

Comment: path("." is going to be relative from the current location. It's not just a file named dot in some random location. It's more specific than that. What would be interesting is to print the absolute path then do a cwd() and print it again to see if it follows your change directory or not.